# Bitmap.Save() method is not working in Unity source

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bitmap, memorystream

I wanna implement 'Bitmap to Texture2D' function in Unity.

I learned to make Texture2D instance, use this syntax below.

```
// **LoadImage(byte[] arr)** can load byte array data and make Texture2D
var data = BitmapToByteMethod(bitmap);

var textureCanvas = new Texture2D(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
textureCanvas.LoadImage(data);
textureCanvas.Apply();
```

To make this function I did like this.

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
    EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

// this is the point error occurred.

    bitmap.Save(memoryStream, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
    //bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

First, I have a bitmap image.
Second, Convert Bitmap to byte array. 
(It works well in my c# sample project.) But when I try to run that function in Unity, Unity program shut down after do 'Bitmap.Save()' method.

I'm beginner of Unity so this is not easy to solve the problems.. below is the source sample code in my project.

Comment: You are saying that this line `bitmap.Save(memoryStream, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);` causes a failure ?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, you're right. I fixed sample code.

Comment: Good. Now what's the error?

Comment: @Thomas There is no error message. Unity program is shut down without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Drawing` is not supported by Unity3D. Probably because it's based on GDI+ and Unity is multiplatform, so it couldn't be used anywhere but on Windows (Mono has its own version of GDI+ for *nix systems, but it doesn't work with Unity either). The official reason seems to be "System.Drawing doesn't work with OpenGL/DirectX".

There seem to be some hacks you could use to make this work, but it only makes sense if you want to stick to Windows. If you want to go this way, there's an answer on the Unity3D forums that should help you - http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/253571/view.html

Comment: You mean, Is that problem about System.Drawing doesn't work?
but I use class **Bitmap**, making image file and so on,  it works fine.
Not working with saving image data to memory stream..

Comment: @FragrantJH `Bitmap` is part of `System.Drawing`. It seems that some things work no some platforms (you might be able to save the bitmap to a file, for example), but it's still unsupported. Why don't you just use `Texture2D`?

Comment: I want to use like Bitmap to Texture2D because I have to crop the image after read. I think there are no clear information. I think I should read image file after cropping. Thanks a lot.